# Can I change Homebrew's prefix?

Tags: homebrew

Somehow, my Homebrew install has a `prefix` of ~/.rvm. I'd like to set it to the default of `/usr/local`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Simply install homebrew in `/user/local`?

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't intuitive to me (and perhaps others) that this was the only way.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Looks like I need to

- Uninstall Homebrew. [Here's a script to help](https://gist.github.com/mxcl/1173223)
- Reinstall it, using the desired prefix
- Reinstall all my formulae

I got a list of my current formulae with `brew list`.

Comment: 'Reinstall it, using the desired prefix' - could you please clarify how to do that?

Comment: Very incomplete answer!

Comment: incomplete answer

Comment: very incomplete answer, what the detail step of 'Reinstall it, using the desired prefix'

Answer (score 7):

Some of Homebrew's bottles (binary packages) can only be used with the default
prefix (/usr/local) like e.g. `rust`. But if you still want to install it with a different prefix, then use:

```
arch -arm64 brew install rust
```

If you want to know, which prefix you already using:

```
brew config | grep HOMEBREW_PREFIX
```

In my case it is `HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /opt/homebrew`

Answer (score 6):

For the benefit of anyone who's had to do a manual install of Homebrew.

Taking a look at the actual brew file is the line:

```
HOMEBREW_PREFIX="${HOMEBREW_BREW_FILE%/*/*}"
```

It turns out it gets the prefix automatically from the parent directory of the install location, unless;

```
# Try to find a /usr/local HOMEBREW_PREFIX where possible (for bottles)
if [[ -L "/usr/local/bin/brew" ]]
then
  USR_LOCAL_BREW_FILE_DIRECTORY="$(symlink_target_directory "/usr/local/bin/brew" "/usr/local/bin")"
  USR_LOCAL_HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY="${USR_LOCAL_BREW_FILE_DIRECTORY%/*}"
  if [[ "$HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY" = "$USR_LOCAL_HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY" ]]
  then
    HOMEBREW_PREFIX="/usr/local"
  fi
fi
```

This'll grab the prefix value from the parent directory of any symlink to the brew executable so long as the Homebrew install directory is down stream from that directory (like /usr/local/Homebrew)

If you've manually installed directly into the usr/local/ directory, you'll still want to go and put a symlink in the usr/local/bin folder to your Homebrew/bin/brew executable to get the correct prefix path. That'll also avoid you needing to add the Homebrew/bin folder directly to your $PATH as well.

Answer (score -3):

Can you not set it with `brew --prefix <prefix>` ?
Running just `brew --prefix` will return the current prefix. I am assuming you are getting the common warning about the prefix in `brew doctor`.

Comment: `brew --prefix <formula>` displays the prefix for a given formula, e.g. `brew --prefix git` prints `/usr/local/opt/git`.